# How to add predefine macro for nvcc?

Tags: c++, qt, cuda, macros

I am currently compiling a Qt project which integrates OpenMesh and CUDA together. Since I have to use nvcc to compile the project, I found an error from the OpenMesh:

```
J:\OpenMesh2.4\include\OpenMesh/Core/System/compiler.hh(109) : fatal error C1189:
#error :  "You have to define _USE_MATH_DEFINES in the compiler settings!"
```

Since the compiler is nvcc not vc compiler, even I add the macro in the "preprocessor definitions", the error still appears. I just wonder if there is a way to add this macro for the nvcc? 
I also tried to manually add this macro in one of my header which include the open mesh headers. The above error is gone but the compile gives another strange error about the source code of openmesh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution: add -D followed by the macro in the nvcc flag...

Comment: `-DNAME=value`, documentation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31066184/how-to-add-predefine-macro-for-nvcc